# A sequence $(x_n)$ with infinite range $T$ converges if and only if $T$ has precisely one accumulation point.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

> Is the following statement true or false?
>
> A sequence $(x_n)$ with infinite range $T$ converges if and only if $T$ has precisely one accumulation point.

I know that the statement is false, but I cannot seem to think of a nice counterexample to provide. Can anyone please show me one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$
x_n = \begin{cases} \frac 1 n \text{, if } n \text{ is even} \\
n \text{, otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
Then $(x_n)_n$ has precisely one accumulation point, but doesn't converge.

Note that the other implication holds. A convergent sequence in $\mathbb R$ with infinite range has precisely one accumulation point, namely its limit.